# Problem in writing the equation: missing delimiter

Tags: math-mode

I tried a lot but unable to solve this equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 f\left\( x,y,\omega,\theta,\sigma x,\sigma y \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma x,\sigma y} exp\left\[\frac{-1}{2}\right\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sigma x}\right)^{2}\right)\left+\left(\left(\frac{y}{\sigma y}\right)^{2}\right)+j\omega\left(x \cos\theta + y \sin\theta\right)\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

always showing

> `!Missing delimitter (.inserted).`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's always better to provide a full example, with a `\documentclass{}`, the relevant packages and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` pair.

Comment: `\left\(` is wrong, it's `\left(...` ... oh, Harish already provided a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would typeset the equation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x,y,\omega,\theta,\sigma x,\sigma y)
  = \frac{e^{-1/2}}{2\pi\,\sigma x,\sigma y}
    \Bigl(\frac{x}{\sigma x}\Bigr)^{\mkern -2mu 2}
    \left[+\Bigl(\frac{y}{\sigma y}\Bigr)^{\mkern -2mu 2}
          + j\omega(x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta)\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x,y,\omega,\theta,\sigma x,\sigma y)
  = \frac{\exp(-1/2)}{2\pi\,\sigma x,\sigma y}
    \Bigl(\frac{x}{\sigma x}\Bigr)^{\mkern -2mu 2}
    \left[+\Bigl(\frac{y}{\sigma y}\Bigr)^{\mkern -2mu 2}
          + j\omega(x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta)\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Notice that with either approach you only need a single line.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `\left\(` and `\left\[` which should be `\left(` and `\left[`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
 f\left( x,y,\omega,\theta,\sigma x,\sigma y \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma x,\sigma y} \exp\left[\frac{-1}{2}\right]\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sigma x}\right)^{2}\right)\left[+\left(\left(\frac{y}{\sigma y}\right)^{2}\right)+j\omega\left(x \cos\theta + y \sin\theta\right)\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks better

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
 f\bigl( x,y,\omega,\theta,\sigma x,\sigma y \bigr)&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma x,\sigma y} \exp\biggl[\frac{-1}{2}\biggr]\\
&\qquad\Bigl(\frac{x}{\sigma x}\Bigr)^{2}\Bigl[+\Bigl(\frac{y}{\sigma y}\Bigr)^{2}+j\omega\bigl(x \cos\theta + y \sin\theta\bigr)\Bigr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Harish Kumar: you forgot the `backslash`in front of `exp`.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- unless i'm hallucinating, the two pairs of `\left` delimiters in your first sentence are the same, so i am confused.  i did spot a `\left+` in the original.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was confused too thinking what that `\left+` is doing there? I was uncertain of what to put and there is also a redundant `+` in the equation. So I am not sure of what the equation is. It is a mess IMO. :-)